How to Text-to-Speech in Tauri React App?
I have a tauri react app. i want to use text to speech in the app.
app work like - app get a string from realtime server and the tauri app convert string to speech and play it.
can someone give me a solution to convert a text to speech in tauri react app.
i couldn't find a good solution for it.
thanks.

for the time being there is no official plugin(https://v2.tauri.app/plugin/) to do TTS, you need to develop a plugin by your self, check https://v2.tauri.app/develop/plugins/develop-mobile/
